# R: fill in cells with values from different rows

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I’m trying to fill NAs in a row with values from a different row. These rows are “linked” by a case number. I want to write an if loop that goes through the entire data frame and does this. But I think I don’t grasp the R language well enough. Can anybody help me?

The data frame:

```
CASE <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
SERIAL <-c("AB",NA, NA, "CD", NA, NA)
REF <- c(NA, 1, 1, NA, 4, 4)
PA <- c(4, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA)
PE <- c(NA, 2, NA, NA, 1, NA)
PE2 <- c(NA, NA, 3, NA, NA, 3)

df <- data.frame (CASE, SERIAL, REF, PA, PE, PE2)

  CASE SERIAL REF PA PE PE2
    1     AB  NA  4  NA  NA
    2   <NA>   1 NA   2  NA
    3   <NA>   1 NA  NA   3
    4     CD  NA  2  NA  NA
    5   <NA>   4 NA   1  NA
    6   <NA>   4 NA  NA   3
```

In the row CASE = 1, I want to fill in the empty PE and PE2 with the values from the rows below, which reference the line (by REF = 1). In the line CASE = 4, I want to fill in the empty PE and PE2 with the values from the rows below, which reference the line (by REF = 4). The lines with no serial number only serve to fill the lines 1 and 4, so to speak. There is no way to collect the data directly into the corresponding lines. I tried this for loop, but don't know how to refrence the values correctly?

```
for (i in 1:dim(df)[1]{
  if (data$SERIAL[i]==NA){
    [data$CASE[data$REF[i]],PE] <- data$PE[i]
    [data$CASE[data$REF[i]],PE2] <- data$PE2[i]}
}
)
```

Expected output:

```
  CASE SERIAL REF PA PE PE2
1    1     AB  NA  4  2   3
2    2   <NA>   1 NA  2  NA
3    3   <NA>   1 NA NA   3
4    4     CD  NA  2  1   3
5    5   <NA>   4 NA  1  NA
6    6   <NA>   4 NA NA   3
```

Comment: Can you provide an expcted output for your example input? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `dplyr` solution, but perhaps it would work:

```
df %>%
  mutate(REF = ifelse(is.na(REF), CASE, REF)) %>% 
  group_by(REF) %>% 
  summarise(SERIAL = first(SERIAL), 
            across(c(PA, PE, PE2), ~sum(.x, na.rm=TRUE))) %>% 
  rename("CASE" = "REF")

# # A tibble: 2 x 5
#   CASE SERIAL    PA    PE   PE2
#   <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1 AB         4     2     3
# 2     4 CD         2     1     3
```

Comment: Wow thank you, this is the best solution! Because it also works with "mixed" rows, i.e. if a row referencing AB appears late, below CD. Can you explain to me, what "summarise(SERIAL = first(SERIAL)" and "~sum(.x, na.rm=TRUE)" do?

Comment: `first(SERIAL)` takes the first value of serial in the group and `~sum(.x, na.rm=TRUE)` calculates the sum of the `PA`, `PE` and `PE2` columns with listwise deletion.  Since there is only one non-missing number for each, it just returns that number.

Answer (score 1):

```
withSerial = subset(df, !is.na(SERIAL))

withSerial
#  CASE SERIAL REF PA PE PE2
#1    1     AB  NA  4 NA  NA
#4    4     CD  NA  2 NA  NA

noSerialwithRef = subset(df, is.na(SERIAL) & !is.na(REF))

noSerialwithRef
#  CASE SERIAL REF PA PE PE2
#2    2   <NA>   1 NA  2  NA
#3    3   <NA>   1 NA NA   3
#5    5   <NA>   4 NA  1  NA
#6    6   <NA>   4 NA NA   3

withSerial$PE = subset(noSerialwithRef, !is.na(PE))$PE
withSerial$PE2 = subset(noSerialwithRef, !is.na(PE2))$PE2

withSerial
#  CASE SERIAL REF PA PE PE2
#1    1     AB  NA  4  2   3
#4    4     CD  NA  2  1   3
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** Added `library(tidyr)` thanks to Martin Gal and added alternative code suggested by Martin Gal:

Here is another `dplyr` way:

1. fill `SERIAL`
2. use `lead` in the grouped_columns
3. keep only first rows of gorups with `slice(1)`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

  df %>% 
    fill(SERIAL, .direction = "down") %>% 
    group_by(SERIAL) %>% 
    mutate(PE = lead(PE),
            PE2 = lead(PE2,2)) %>% 
    slice(1)

# Alternative and better (suggested by Martin Gal):
df %>% fill(-c(CASE, SERIAL), .direction = "up") %>% drop_na()
```

```
   CASE SERIAL   REF    PA    PE   PE2
  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 AB        NA     4     2     3
2     4 CD        NA     2     1     3
```

Comment: (1) Why not simply `df %>% fill(-c(CASE, SERIAL), .direction = "up") %>% drop_na()`? (2) You are missing `library(tidyr)`. :-)

Comment: Thanks Martin Gal. I missed your comment. Now I have updated!!!